# How to plot complex functions on the paper by your hand?

Tags: complex-analysis, graphing-functions

I want to know the exact method of plotting complex function used by human, computer, and whatever who can do mathematics.
For example how should I plot this : $w = u+iv$ , $z = x+iy$ , $w= f(z)= z^2$
I'm completely confused imagining the complex functions and I want to know how you would imagine such functions and do mathematics with it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you understand that you can't plot functions from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: No, you mean it's not possible to plot such function?

Comment: Yes, it isn't possible to plot such functions in the traditional sense of 'plot'.

Comment: you're confused by not precisely defining, what you have and what you want.

Comment: So please, give me some guidance, I'm completely confused doing math with complex variables, what is the modern definition of plotting a function?

Comment: It seems I have some problems in the terms, could you please tell me why can't we plot R^2 to R^2?

Comment: @MrWho You can't plot from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$ for the reason *mathematics2x2life* gives in his answer. See [this](http://www.pacifict.com/ComplexFunctions.html) link for a different way of plotting functions.

Comment: Such function is like having a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is not possible to plot on paper.

@GitGud It was a typos. Thanks for the correction

Comment: of cause, you may plot 3D surface with the 4th dimension described by the color, or something like that...

Comment: I recall some of my lecturers plotting complex functions by showing how the function transforms a particular shape, but I'm not sure how standard this is.

Comment: ISBN 0-07-008496-3, Complex variables and applications by James Ward Brown and Ruel V. Churchill. Section 10 'Mappings'. Page 28.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What free tools can I use to plot complex functions on the complex plane?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191604/what-free-tools-can-i-use-to-plot-complex-functions-on-the-complex-plane)

Answer (score 5):

You don't plot these. To plot them would require $2$ axes to plot the real and imaginary components of the inputs and they it would require another $2$ axes to plot the real and imaginary components of the outputs, totaling $4$ axes. However, we are unable to plot in $4$-dimensions in our $3$ dimensional world. So we must make a choice: plot the imaginary part of the output or the real part of the output. For example, take the function $f(z)=z^2$. Then we have
$$
f(2+i)=(2+i)^2=4+4i-1=3+4i
$$
We could then plot the imaginary part of the output, $4i$. So this would be the same as plotting the point $(2,1,4)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

**NOTE.** This isn't the only thing we could plot. For example, another common choice is to plot the absolute value of the output. In our example above, we would have $f(2+i)=3+4i$. Then we know that $|3+4i|=\sqrt{25}=5$. So we would plot the point $(2,1,5)$. It all depends on the choice of the final variable to plot while the $2$ first axes are almost always the real and imaginary components of the input, respectively.

Comment: What's the problem? Couldn't we plot (2,1,4) in the R^3?!

Comment: Yes, we could and we do. That's the point. We can plot that but we cannot plot the point $(2,1,3,4)$ which would be needed to properly visualize the output of $f(2+i)$ in my example.

Comment: Plotting complex function is still hard for me to grasp!

Comment: It should be given that it is humanly impossible to do as it needs to be done, as I explained. Moreover, it's not that important in Complex Analysis as even if we do plot, it is a computer program that does the work for us. More important to learn the theory like the Cauchy-Goursat Theorem, Residue Theorem, Cauchy Integral Formula, etc.

Comment: However, I want to have geometric imagination of what I'm really doing, if you know any article or something which has explained plotting clearly please let me know.

Comment: I can't think of any explanation that isn't equivalent to or simpler than the one I gave here. It boils down to that we can't plot in $4$-dimensions. However, if you want a **fantastic** geometric description of complex numbers and complex analysis from a visual perspective, then look no further than Visual Complex by. Tristam Needham. I consider it one of the best Mathematics textbooks yet written. It does a fantastic job of what you want and more. It reads more like a 'normal' book than a textbook, flowing smoothly from idea to idea and chapter to chapter.

Answer (score 4):

I just wanted to point out that I wrote a Python package, [cplot](https://github.com/nschloe/cplot), that makes plotting complex-valued functions fairly simple.
It combines [domain coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring) and contour lines for constant arg/abs.
e.g., for $\sin(z)/z$:

```
import cplot
import numpy as np


def f(z):
    return np.sin(z) / z


plt = cplot.plot(f, (-7.0, +7.0, 400), (-7.0, +7.0, 400))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can plot such functions!  Look at https://people.math.osu.edu/fowler.291/phase/

for instance.  The color at a point tells you the phase of the image of that point.  To see what the base "phase chart" is, just plot the identity function $z$.

If you wanted phase and modulus info, you could do a 3D plot colored by phase.  I did that too using webGL and cannot find it now.  Will update this later when I do...

Answer (score 0):

Like Steven Gubkin says, coloring by phase can give you excellent geometric intuitions. I put together this Python code while I was taking complex analysis, let me know what you think: https://github.com/seaplant3/complex-plotting

It uses contours (like an elevation map) to show magnitude, I found  that was the  easiest way to keep everything visible.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/941960)

Comment: What 'essential parts of the answer' are missing?

Comment: Your relevant Python code, in case the link changes/goes down.