# What free tools can I use to plot complex functions on the complex plane?

Tags: complex-numbers, graphing-functions, wolfram-alpha

I would like to plot $y = e^{ix}$ to view the imaginary unit circle and then change different parameters to see what happens. I am having trouble getting wolfram alpha to do this though. Is there a good way?

Comment: It woirks if you rewrite this as [x=cos(t), y=sin(t)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%3Dcos(t),+y%3Dsin(t))

Comment: If you know some basic programming python, R, and sage have some pretty good mathematical graphic libraries. And if you're not familiar with them, I would recommend it. It's not to hard to learn.  I would say your easiest option is to learn how to rewrite complex functions as parametrics as Henry hinted at and use a standard graphing utility.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to plot complex functions on the paper by your hand?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620736/how-to-plot-complex-functions-on-the-paper-by-your-hand)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you must define your complex function  as a curve in $\Bbb R^3$ using a parameter, by example $t$, and separating each coordinate.

In our case we have that

$$f(x):=e^{ix}=\cos (x)+i\sin (x)$$

then we can transform the graph of the above function in a parametric curve in $\Bbb R^3$ writing

$$\gamma (t)=t\cdot{\bf i}+\cos(t)\cdot{\bf j}+\sin(t)\cdot{\bf k}$$

Then the image of $\gamma $ is the graph of $f$. Using [Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/graphing) we can write in the algebra view

```
Curve[t,cos(t),sin(t),t,-5,5]
```

and the graph can be viewed in the 3DView tab. Indeed Geogebra is an extraordinary tool due to it simplicity and portability. We can define applets easily as [this](https://www.geogebra.org/m/tqvmMcY3) (with little work we can add text boxes or buttons for any kind of interactivity!)

Using the Wolfram language (in [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ParametricPlot3D%5B%7Bt,Cos%5Bt%5D,Sin%5Bt%5D%7D,%7Bt,-5,5%7D%5D) or the Wolfram programming lab) we can write

```
ParametricPlot3D[{t,Cos[t],Sin[t]},{t,-5,5}]
```

And with a very similar code we can write in [SageMathCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/)

```
t = var('t'); parametric_plot3d([t,cos(t),sin(t)],(t,-5,5), aspect_ratio=[1,1,1], zoom=1.5)
```

(the result can be seen [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwNxUEKgCAQBdCrzC6FKZBwFZ4kRAZrIVQj-mnR6ZO3eKBArzQzYbIbVWlyn2glp3op1sPs4KzdwHIvzyiyAc-evWWSXs-M1ARFw-54iEyf6h3c4u0PPOgcYA==&lang=sage)).

There are a lot of different tools to graph online, by example I discovered today the library [plotly](https://plot.ly/feed/) that can be used in many programming languages (and online too!). It homepage is full of tutorials for any kind of plot, in our case we have a tutorial for a curve in $\Bbb R^3$ [here](http://help.plot.ly/make-a-3d-line-chart/).

Answer (score 3):

[cplot](https://github.com/nschloe/cplot) is a Python package I wrote. It uses  [domain coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring) and associates brightness to the modules of $f(z)$, and hue to its argument.

For the function $f(z) = z^6 + 1$:

```
import cplot

plt = cplot.plot(lambda z: z ** 6 + 1, (-1.5, +1.5, 400), (-1.5, +1.5, 400))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found that this website is pretty good.  I would prefer if it plotted in 3D, but you can get a pretty good sense using the color mappings in 2D.

Basically what it will do is display phase as a color and the magnitude as the lightness/darkess of the color.  (Larger magnitudes get represented by lighter colors.)

http://jutanium.github.io/ComplexNumberGrapher/

Comment: Nice, but can't change range, and couldn't handle the sum `z ** (-1) - z ** (-2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try https://treena.org/lesson/complex-grapher
It should do most of what you want. (Disclaimer: I helped build it)

Future Note: We've just remade this whole thing from scratch for the https://www.3blue1brown.com/blog/some1 contest. It's been neglected since then, but it's alive again.

Comment: Great addition. Does it accept $\bar z$? Does it accept a formula for the curve in the $z$ plane?