# What online graphing tools handle complex numbers well?

Tags: functions, complex-numbers, graphing-functions, roots-of-unity

> What online graphing tools handle complex numbers well?

Desmos is generally excellent by breaking functions down into their real and imaginary parts and plotting on the Euclidean plane. For example it can relatively easily graph:

$f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb C$

$f(x)=x\cdot\exp{(2\pi i\log_{\frac23}x)}$

as shown [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/w1ngrpm43z), and it displays and prints nicely.

But I want to plot $f(x)=x\cdot\exp{(2\pi i\log_{\frac{-1}3}x)}$ which is a little more tricky as it requires the imaginary unit within the exponent because $\log(-1/3)=i\pi-\log(3)$

Is there a way with desmos, or an easy-to-use alternative tool?

Comment: Your $log_b$ function with a negative base $b$ is uncommon, I would even say not acceptable as such. No surprise that this software doesn't find it sympathetical...

Comment: Wolfram Alpha is my favorite !

Comment: @Peter are you able to plot the points of $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb C, f(x)=x\cdot\exp{(2\pi i\log_{\frac23}x)}$ in Wolfram Alpha like here https://www.desmos.com/calculator/w1ngrpm43z?  I use Wolfram lots but always use Desmos because I've never been able or known how to plot those points in Wolfram Alpha. e.g. how do you give it a list of integers?

Comment: @user334732 I am pretty sure there is a way, but I did not try much in this direction. But other users of Wolfram Alpha should be on this site. Someone might know how it works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What free tools can I use to plot complex functions on the complex plane?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191604/what-free-tools-can-i-use-to-plot-complex-functions-on-the-complex-plane)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [WolframCloud](http://develop.open.wolframcloud.com/app/), it is Mathematica with some limitations (computing time, ...)

```
f[x_]:= x Exp[2 Pi  I  Log[-1/3,x]];
t = Table[{Re[f[x]],Im[f[x]]},{x,1,10}];
ListPlot[t, Joined->True]
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

To include labels you can use something like this

```
f[x_]:= x Exp[2 Pi  I  Log[-1/3,x]];
t = Table[{Re[f[x]],Im[f[x]]},{x,1,10}];
ListLinePlot[t->Range[10], PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10},LabelingFunction->Left]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can you get it to look like this: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/w1ngrpm43z ?  I can already graph what you show with wolfram.

Comment: @user334732 Like this?

Comment: Are you seeing a spiral in the complex plane when you click on the Desmos link, with each point plotted labelled with its associated odd number?

Comment: That script does actually look right, just the graph doesn't look how I expected! Is it possible to label the points too? I'll investigate further based on this.

Comment: @user334732 Added an edit